# How to delete the delimiter in a string only from a particular position?

Tags: regex, r, string, replace, strsplit

I have the following text:

```
//@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D//@E:    
//@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D//
```

I want to delete only the `//` from this string *if* there is no `@` associated with it.

The output I want is:

```
 //@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D//@E:    
 //@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D
```

Comment: can you do that in 3 steps: 1) replace //@ with something like !!@@; 2) Replace // with empty string; 3) replace !!@@ with //@?

Answer (score 3):

You can search using negative lookahead:

```
//(?!@)
```

and replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aE1hY5/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capturing group and replace with back-reference. This way, you do not even need to specify `perl=T`:

```
str <- '//@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D//@E: //@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D//'
gsub('//([^@]|$)', '\\1', str)
```

**Explanation of the pattern:**

- `//` - 2 literal slashes
- `([^@]|$)` - capturing group 1 that matches a non-`@` (with `[^@]`) or the end of string `$`.
- `\\1` - is the back-reference to the captured group contents to put it back into the replaced string.

Output of the [demo program](https://ideone.com/ND3azt):

```
[1] "//@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D//@E: //@A:Good!//@B: Wow!//@C: How come?@D"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\\/\\/(?!@)
```

You can try this with `gsub` and `perl=True`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/34

Comment: R language doesn't use delimiters, so escaping slashes is not needed.